# Display ToolTip on hovering Column Header of List Control in MFC C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a scenario where I need to display a tooltip on hovering of Column Header in List Control in MFC C++.

I have used the message handler `OnMouseMove()`, but when on hovering of Column header it's not going into `OnMouseMove()` function but it's going into when I move on to list items.

Can someone suggest the better way.

```
void CMatSizeEditList::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    int nRow = HitTest(point);
    int nCol = ColumnFromPoint(point);

    m_cToolTip.AddTool(&m_cMatSizeList, IDC_MAT_UNITS);
    m_cToolTip.Activate(TRUE);

    CListControl::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

BOOL CMatSizeEditList::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    m_cToolTip.RelayEvent(pMsg);
    return CXCtrlDialog::PreTranslateMessage(pMsg);
}
```

How to add tooltip for column header of `CListCtrl`?

Answer (score 0):

Like you do with adding tooltip to anywhere, use a `CToolTipCtrl`. Here you need to catch nofications about header resizing (e.g. `HDN_ENDTRAC`) and recalculate the rect to pass to `CToolTipCtrl:SetToolInfo`.